# Moving windows in GNU screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I use GNU screen daily and I wonder is it possible to move windows in the window-list. Say I have

```
 Num Name                                                   Flags

    0 emacs                                                      $
    1 root                                                       $
    2 bash                                                       $
    3 something-else                                             $
```

and I want the "root" window to become 0th, so I can access it with C-a 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using the version above 4.1.0, you can use following keys to manage window on windowlist.

- `,` Switch numbers with the previous window.
- `.` Switch numbers with the next window.
- `K` Kill the selected window.

In your case,

- `C-a` `"` (show windowlist)
- select `1 root` (moving cursor key or type `1`)
- type `,`
- type `0` (and exit window list)

Answer (score 2):

Use "number" command:

> number [n]
>
> ```
>    Change the current windows number. If the given number n is already used by another window, both windows exchange their numbers.
> ```
>
> If no argument is specified, the current win‐
>          dow number (and title) is shown.

Press "C-a :" and type "number `<num>`" to move window to a specified place.